# Visible row level actions in first column in lightning:datatable as opposed to actions within a dropdown at the end of the row

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Using lightning:datatable (the way it is today), is it possible to show row level actions in the first column with each action individually visible when the datatable loads (exactly how Salesforce Classic renders it's row level actions in list views) as opposed to what the out of the box functionality in lightning does today which is stack all actions together in one dropdown and throw'em towards the end?

> Desired:

[image]

> Today:

[image]

Comment: Same behavior is in standard list view and lightning components, also not sure if this is possible at the moment.

Comment: Right, but I was wondering if there is a programmatic way to control the placement and positioning. We have 20+ columns in the datatable that is pushing the actions all the way to the end, so the users are needing to scroll back and forth and is really frustrating. Plus, needing to click on a dropdown and find and click on the desired action as opposed to seeing the actions right there with the data is hurting adoption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make the actions visible in the current version of lightning:datatable, as they will always appear in menu form, but you can specify the action column anywhere you'd like aside from where the checkboxes are (if enabled).

Copying the [example from the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm) and modifying it slightly:

```
    cmp.set('v.mycolumns', [
        {label: 'Actions', type: 'action', rowActions: helper.getRowActions.bind(this, cmp) },
        {label: 'Opportunity name', fieldName: 'opportunityName', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Confidence', fieldName: 'confidence', type: 'percent', cellAttributes:
         { iconName: { fieldName: 'trendIcon' }, iconPosition: 'right' }},
        {label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency', typeAttributes: { currencyCode: 'EUR'}},
        {label: 'Contact Email', fieldName: 'contact', type: 'email'},
        {label: 'Contact Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone'}
    ]);
```

Results in:

[image: Actions in Left Column]

Please note that if you've got 20 columns in a table, you might want to rethink your design, such as allowing users to toggle some columns, or not showing all of them by default.